# How to call a model function insider another controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i have my controller function like this:

```
private function _send_refund_scores($userId,$scores,$orderId){
            $this->loadModel('Score');
            $rtn = $this->Score->refund_user_scores($userId,$scores,$orderId);
            if(!empty($rtn)){
                return true;
            }else return false;
}
```

while in another model Score , I have model function `refund_user_scores`;

the error like this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'refund_user_scores' at line 1

so,any idea?

Comment: Check if `refund_user_scores` is a private or public function.

Comment: Is Score defined inside a plugin? If so you need to use `loadModel()` with the plugin syntax: `$this->loadModel('PluginName.Score')`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have defined `refund_user_scores()` as a private function in model `Score`.

That is why you are getting this error.

Comment: thanks,i   find the problem: the controller and the model should be in the same folder,so the controller can find the model function

Comment: @lipengyu this doesn't sound correct. Your models and controllers should be in their respective Model and Controller folders. It sounds like you might have a bigger issue with the structure of your code!

Comment: i mean there's a parent model folder containing serval models and a parent controller folder also containing serval controllers;and one of the child controller want to call another model function,so the model's parent folder should be inside  the same folder with the parent controller folder.